# How to adapt the equation of Gaussian mechanism noise based on number of executions

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a differentially private machine learning model. I'm using the Gaussian mechanism to calculate the required noise amount based on pre-defined privacy budget value

The equation to find the noise amount is below

$\sigma = \sqrt{2ln(1.25/)} / \varepsilon $

I'm aware that when the model performs several epochs, say 15, I will need to use either the naive composition or the advanced composition theorem to calculate the new $\varepsilon'$

$$\varepsilon' = \sqrt{2k\log(1/\delta)}\varepsilon + k \varepsilon (e^\varepsilon-1)$$

**1. I'm interested to know how to adapt the first equation and use it to compute the total amount of noise to be dded based on the number of executions (epochs)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you mention to get $\sigma$ given $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ is **only correct for $\varepsilon<1$**. It's also not tight.

If you use Gaussian noise on multiple statistics, each of sensitivity 1, and want to get the tightest possible privacy guarantees, then you should use the [Analytic Gaussian Mechanism](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06530.pdf) instead (Theorem 8), replacing $\Delta$ with the square root of the number of your statistics. It's tight and works for any value of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$.

The only problem with that approach is that there's no formula giving $\sigma$ as a simple function of $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ and $\Delta$; so you have to do some binary search to find the best possible value (and be careful about how you do the floating-point calculations). [Here is an example](https://github.com/google/differential-privacy/blob/327972c1ae710e8cd0a4754fffdd78c3500272ee/go/noise/gaussian_noise.go#L311) from our open-source differential privacy library.

Finally, if what you want to do is train a model in a DP way, I would suggest using existing tooling, like [TensorFlow Privacy](https://github.com/tensorflow/privacy), rather than rolling your own.